# Elasticsearch aggregation by arrays of String

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I have an ElasticSearch index, where I store telephony transactions (SMS, MMS, Calls, etc ) with their associated costs.

The key of these documents are the MSISDN (**MSISDN = phone number**). In my app, I know that there are group of users. Each users can have one or more MSISDN.

Here is the mapping of this kind of documents :

```
"mappings" : {
      "cdr" : {
        "properties" : {
          "callDatetime" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "callSource" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "callType" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "callZone" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "calledNumber" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "companyKey" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "consumption" : {
            "properties" : {
              "data" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "voice" : {
                "type" : "long"
              }
            }
          },
          "cost" : {
            "type" : "double"
          },
          "country" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "included" : {
            "type" : "boolean"
          },
          "msisdn" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "network" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

**My goal and issue :**

My goal is to make a query that retrieve **cost** by **callType** by **group**. But groups are not represented in ElasticSearch, only in my PostgreSQL database.

So I will make a method that retrieves all the MSISDN for every existing group, and get something like a List of String arrays, containing every MSISDN within each group.

Let's say I have something like :

```
"msisdn_by_group" : [
    {
       "group1" : ["01111111111", "02222222222", "033333333333", "044444444444"]
    },
    {
       "group2" : ["05555555555","06666666666"]
    }
]
```

Now, I will use this to generate an Elasticsearch query. I want to make with an aggregation, the sum of the cost, for all those terms in different buckets, and then split it again by callType. (to make a stackedbar chart).

I've tried several things, but didn't manage to make it work (histogram, buckets, term and sum was mainly the keyword i'm playing with).

If somebody here can help me with the order, and the keywords I can use to achieve this, it would be great :) Thanks

EDIT :
Here is my last try :
**QUERY:**

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "cost_histogram": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "callType"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "cost_histogram_sum" : {
                    "sum": {
                        "field": "cost"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I go the expected result, but it missing the "group" split, as I don't know how to pass the MSISDN arrays as a criteria :

**RESULT :**

```
"aggregations": {
    "cost_histogram": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "data",
          "doc_count": 5925,
          "cost_histogram_sum": {
            "value": 0
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "sms_mms",
          "doc_count": 5804,
          "cost_histogram_sum": {
            "value": 91.76999999999995
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "voice",
          "doc_count": 5299,
          "cost_histogram_sum": {
            "value": 194.1196
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "sms_mms_plus",
          "doc_count": 35,
          "cost_histogram_sum": {
            "value": 7.2976
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Maybe show the query you have now and explain what is still missing?

Comment: @Val of course I forgot it, my bad ! see my edit please

Comment: You need another `terms` aggregation that wraps your current one.

Comment: Why not storing the group id inside your documents as well? You can look it up at indexing time and then your documents are self-contained.

Comment: At the time the documents are being imported, we can't know to which group(s) the msisdn is belonging. It's an external Groovy job that do the import in ES. Anyway thank you very much for your help, I want to add another "terms" agg but I don't know how to build it so it can split by string array. I hope I'm clear enough in my explanation

Comment: thanks for your help @Val I found how to get what I want, I used a `filter` aggregation on top of what I did before, and just duplicated the query for each group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found out how to make this with one query, but it's damn a long query because it repeats for every group, but I have no choise. I'm using the "filter" aggregator.

Here is a working example based on the array I wrote in my question above :

*POST localhost:9200/cdr/_search?size=0*

```
{
    "query": {
        "term" : {
            "companyKey" : 1
        }   
    },
    "aggs" : {
        "group_1_split_cost": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "should": [{
                        "bool": {
                            "must": {
                                "match": {
                                    "msisdn": "01111111111"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },{
                        "bool": {
                            "must": {
                                "match": {
                                    "msisdn": "02222222222"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },{
                        "bool": {
                            "must": {
                                "match": {
                                    "msisdn": "03333333333"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },{
                        "bool": {
                            "must": {
                                "match": {
                                    "msisdn": "04444444444"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "cost_histogram": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "callType"
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "cost_histogram_sum" : {
                            "sum": {
                                "field": "cost"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "group_2_split_cost": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "should": [{
                        "bool": {
                            "must": {
                                "match": {
                                    "msisdn": "05555555555"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },{
                        "bool": {
                            "must": {
                                "match": {
                                    "msisdn": "06666666666"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "cost_histogram": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "callType"
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "cost_histogram_sum" : {
                            "sum": {
                                "field": "cost"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks to the newer versions of Elasticsearch we can now nest very deep aggregations, but it's still a bit too bad that we can't pass arrays of values to an "OR" operator or something like that. It could reduce the size of those queries, I guess. Even if they are a bit special and used in niche cases, as mine.

Comment: Did you find any better way of doing this? What if values are dynamic?

Comment: you can change that should on misdn field to a terms query, like `terms: {"msisdn": [<comma separated values>]}`